# Модуль - Связанные материалы и meta тэг Keywords в Joomle

Tags: php, javascript, html, joomla, joomla3

Добрый день, всем! Есть сайт на Joomla 3, в админке сайта есть несколько материалов и модуль - Связанные материалы, в материале есть поле мета тэг keywords, как связать несколько материалов с помощью данного модуля? Как сделать чтобы на одной странице отображались несколько связанных материалов с превью? Что писать в поле мета тэг keywords в данном случае?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен!, вы хотите посредством модуля показать связанные материалы на сайте? а при чём тут поле для метатега ?

Comment: Arsen, да хочу показать связанные материалы посредством модуля, есть несколько страниц на сайте День рождения, Другие праздники, Корпоративы, на которых в конце этих страниц есть похожие связанные материалы с изображениями (превью), и  материал  соотносится с категорией с помощью того, что прописано в поле keywords в материале. Например, если это материал День рождения в keywords прописано День рождения.

Comment: Arsen, Мне нужно сделать тоже самое только на главной странице сайта вывести связанные материалы День рождения, Другие праздники, и т.д., когда я добавляю модуль и прописываю несколько keywords выводится только один материал Другие праздники на главной странице сайта. Как это исправить?

Comment: В  в настройках модуля какое число вставленно "Макс. показ материалов" ? возможно проблема может быть от нескольких keywords, для проверки вставьте один keywords, если работает - вставьте второй и так проверяйте где конфликт

Comment: Arsen, Макс. показ материалов в модуле сейчас 6. Вы немного меня не поняли мне нужно вывести на главной странице 6 последних связанных материалов из разных категорий День рождения, Другие праздники, Корпоративы. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Насколько я помню данный модуль должен работать на страницах категорий, т.е материалы должны быть связанны ключевыми словами но в одной категории! (если мне память не именяет )

Comment: Arsen, да все правильно у меня уже есть материалы которые относятся к одной категории. А можно сделать вывод 6 последних связанных материалов в не зависимости от категорий к которым они относятся и как это сделать?

Comment: Да конечно можно, однако тут вам готовый пример никто не сможет дать, вам надо посмотреть в коде модуля из какого Модел-я получает данные из базы, найти данную функцию и редактировать логику запроса к базе, однако это может отразиться на другие модули и т.д